# TYPO3 TCA input time open / close

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Developers,

I need for a opening times list a TCA Input Field Array (TYPO3 7.6).
I hope so? :)

Here a Example:

> Monday 08:00 am - 11:00 pm
>
> Tuesday 08:00 am - 11:00 pm
>
> Wednesday 08:00 am - 11:00 pm
>
> Thursday 08:00 am - 11:00 pm
>
> Friday 08:00 am - 11:00 pm
>
> Saturday  08:00 am - 11:00 pm

I need only the input for the Clock/Time.
I take 6 DB-fields for the Days. But i need a opening Time and a closed time.
I need again now 6 new fields for the close-time?

```
'opening_mo' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'Montag',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 15,
        'eval' => 'time',
    ),
),
```

Thanks for Help!

Comment: You should add either `time` or `timesec` to your `eval`-property. That would give you a single field where you can enter one time. Creating an array of times is not so easy in TCA, as single fields. You could create a second table/domain model, where every row/instance is an opening time for one day, make that table editable with IRRE (would look similar to editing images in content elements).

Comment: Hi Jost, thanks for the fast replay!
mhh i am not a Developer :(
U have for me a Code-Example or a Example-Link? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the TCA to make it interpret your data as a time value:

```
'time' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'Opening Times',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'eval' => 'time,required'
    ),
),
```

For a full list of available values for `eval`have a look a the TCA documentation:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Input/Index.html

Comment: jep i now, but than i have one field, i need in one field a solution for the six times.
i dont like six DB-fields!

Comment: You should add that requirement to your question.

Comment: I take 6 DB-fields for the Days. But i need a opening Time and a closed time. I need again now 6 new fields for the close-time?